# Searching for a specific filetype in a folder based on its parent folder

Tags: javascript, search, directory, file-type

I'm trying to set up a system to search for specific files types, in this case .aep, in folders that will change over time

example in a folder called MER is a folder called Mermaid_v03 when this file is updated another department it will become Mermaid_v04 so hard coding the address isn't an option.

So the parent folder always contains the first three letters of folder containing the aep I need in capital letters. I've written the following.

```
//Get the last folder name in the path
var netPath =Folder("//networkpath/MER")
var justName = charFileLoc.substring(charFileLoc.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

var FolderItems = netPath.getFiles();

for (x = 0; x < FolderItems.length; x++) {


//Search for aep
if (FolderItems[i].name.match(justName)) {

    alert("I see a folder that starts with "+justName);  
    var matchFolder = Folder(FolderItems[i]); 

         for (x = 0; x < matchFolder.length; x++) {

            //Search new folder for aep
            if (matchFolder[i].name.match(/\.(aep)$/)){

                alert("I see an aep file called "+matchFolder[i])
               }
            }
       }
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong

Comment: What exactly went wrong -- what do you expect, what do you get? And what's the value of `charFileLoc`? And don't you need case-insensitive match if that remark on "capital letters" is about the AEP suffix?

Comment: Hmm why do you use `i` for your indexes but loop using x?  Also I believe you want to say `var x=0...` in those loops.  Finally, it looks like you're using `x` twice which might be throwing you off.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I changed netPath var when I added it on here to try to make it easier to understand. This is how it should be:

```
//Get the last folder name in the path
var charFileLoc =Folder("//networkpath/MER")
// Grab just the last folder name
var justName = charFileLoc.substring(charFileLoc.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

var FolderItems = charFileLoc.getFiles();

for (x = 0; x < FolderItems.length; x++) {


//Search for aep
if (FolderItems[i].name.match(justName)) {

    alert("I see a folder that starts with "+justName);  
    var matchFolder = Folder(FolderItems[i]); 

         for (x = 0; x < matchFolder.length; x++) {

            //Search new folder for aep
            if (matchFolder[i].name.match(/\.(aep)$/)){

                alert("I see an aep file called "+matchFolder[i])
               }
            }
       }
```

My biggest proplem is using justName to search the beginning of folders using a non case sensitive manner. currently I believe it's trying to match MER exactly. Also when I try to check the files listed in FolderItems they are not displaying the names properly, they are all named ds_store